# MVC Validation not working where base class is in another project

Tags: model-view-controller, validation, annotations

We have a large number of MVC pages using validation annotations on our entity model and other locally defined classes, and these work fine.  However I now have a page whose base class is in another (referenced) project which is not working.

Some of the anotations work ok ("DisplayName", for example) but the validation is not working at all.  For example, when submitting a blank form, TryUpdateModel(object) returns True, despite their being a "Required" validator on both fields.

The "UserListInfo" class in is the referenced project.  I have tried with and without the "Inherits" to no avail.

Any thoughts?

```
<MetadataType(GetType(UserListInfoMetaData))> _
Partial Public Class UserListInfo
    Inherits [Other Project Namespace].UserListInfo
End Class

Public Class UserListInfoMetaData

    <UIHint("HiddenId")> _
    Public Property UserID() As Object

    <DisplayName("Email Address")> _
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="You must enter an Email Address")> _
    <StringLength(150, ErrorMessage:="Cannot be more than 150 characters long.")> _
    Public Property Username() As Object

    <DisplayName("Name")> _
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="You must enter a Name")> _
    <StringLength(150, ErrorMessage:="Cannot be more than 150 characters long.")> _
    Public Property FriendlyName() As Object

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what I seem to have done wrong was to provide a fully qualified path in the "Inherits" statement.  If I import the base class namespace and then use a partially qualified path from that all seems fine!

Ie...

```
<MetadataType(GetType(UserListInfoMetaData))> _
Partial Public Class UserListInfo
    Inherits Bob.Fred.Jim.UserListInfo
End Class
```

Does not work, but...

```
Imports Bob.Fred

Class XYX

    <MetadataType(GetType(UserListInfoMetaData))> _
    Partial Public Class UserListInfo
        Inherits Jim.UserListInfo
    End Class
    .
    .
    .

End Class
```

Does!